# How can I debug why the click event gets removed from a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using chrome in case their developer tools help.

I have an accordion with 5 buttons that opens the section of the accordion.

For some reason now when I open a section, the click event of some other sections is disabled and I can't open them during certain situations.

How can I debug why the click event has been temporarily de-activated on these buttons?

Comment: The click event probably isn't removed.  What are the certain situations when the other tabs aren't opening?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the JavaScript console in Chrome by going to <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Developer</kbd> > <kbd>JavaScript Console</kbd>.

Some methods for debugging include:

- Commenting out one line at a time until something starts to work/not work
- Insert `console.log(true)` or something similar at the beginning of certain blocks to determine the point at which your code stops 'working' (I believe these are referred to as break points.)

Comment: Or if you're a keyboard monkey like me, `F12` will open the Chrome dev tools :)

Comment: Very true. Also, if you're on Mac, you can hit alt+CMD+J.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all event listeners on any DOM object in **Chrome DevTools** > **Elements** and there is **Event Listeners** tab on the right panel.

Here is an example for a downvote button on stackoverflow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What changed?  Hopefully, you've got a good check-in of the working version against which you can compare the now-broken version.

A thought: are you perhaps intercepting the click event on an element that isn't propagated to the accordion element?  To complement answer 1 above, you might start with just the accordion and add stuff until it breaks too.  Depends on how much is going on on your page.

Along these lines, you may assign a quickie click handler to the accordion div.group's with a simple alert or console.log("Click!") to see if you're actually even receiving the event.

You can also check to see if the event listener is still assigned to the section/button by inspecting that element in the Elements window of the Chrome dev tools, and then expanding the "click" section of the "Event Listeners" tab on the right pane.